# Why do many buttons only perform one task?

Tags: javascript, html, events

So I am SUPER new to any sort of development. I'm just getting introduced to JavaScript and my class assignment is to change a box in HTML from a cube to a Rectangle, from Orange to Blue, to Faded Opacity, and to reset it, all via buttons. when I try to add an event listener "click" based on their Id's (boxes 1,2,3,4) the next listener overwrites the previous. So to simplify, I add in this code to my .js file:

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", myFunction); 
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px"; 
}
```

and it all works great. I press button 1 and it turns to a rectangle. When I do the same thing but change it to `style.backgroundColor = "blue"; }` it works like a charm, but removes the first button's functionality. This continues with the Opacity as well. Explain it to me like I'm a five year old, please.

Comment: can you post your code for the other buttons?

Comment: Without being able to see your code, my guess would be that you created four functions all named `myFunction`.

Comment: You need to create multiple myFunction1(), myFunction2(), etc for each button. If you have one function you need to use if/else logic to differentiate which button should do what.

Comment: Perfect. I differentiated the myFunctions and so far so good. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You have created four functions all named myFunction, which is causing a naming collision.

If you don't want to write meaningful names for your functions then you are better off using anonymous functions.  These are functions that have no name at all and are writen directly in the place they will be used.

This way you will avoid having too many functions available in your scope which will avoid naming collisions.

```
document.getElementById("button1")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px"; 
  })
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer his question.  Probably a good idea to include the solution you guys came up with in comments into this answer imo.  :)

Comment: @Brian  yes that's kind of true.  I've added a line to explain what his bug was, and so why this is a good fix.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", makeBigger); 
    document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", makeBlue); 
    document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", makeOrange); 
    document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", makeInvisible); 
    
    function makeBigger() {
      document.getElementById("box").style.fontSize = "36px"; 
    }
    function makeBlue() {
      document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "Blue"; 
    }
    function makeOrange() {
      document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "Orange"; 
    }
    function makeInvisible() {
      document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none"; 
    }
```

```css
#box {
  
  border: solid 1px #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
<button id="button1">
   Bigger
</button>

<button id="button2">
   Blue
</button>

<button id="button3">
   Orange
</button>

<button id="button4">
   Hide
</button>
</div>
<div id="box">

Some stuf and what not
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use a Stack Snippet to put the working example here instead of jsfiddle?

Comment: I guess I should do that.  I got used to JSFIDDLE back in the day on here before they had stack snippet.  I always forget that it's there haha

Comment: @Barmar How do I do that again ?

Comment: Click on the `[<>]` tool.

Answer (score 0):

You don't list your other methods, but if you were to do the following, you'd see each of the methods execute because you've have multiple callbacks assigned to fire when the click event is observed on the DOM element.

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", myFunction); 
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", myFunction2); 

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px"; 
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 0.5;
}
```

For the purposes of just changing these, you could also just combine into a single event handler:

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", myFunction); 

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px"; 
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 0.5;
}
```

Or even split them up so there's a single callback, but it in turn calls multiple functions:

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", myFunction); 

function myFunction1() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px"; 
}

function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 0.5;
}

function myFunction() {
    myFunction1();
    myFunction2();
}
```

Any of these would do what you're looking for.